# Access String after binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I made an application with [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/). The page is divided into several sections, as described here: [Adding Pages in jQuery Mobile](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_pages).
In the second section, that acts as an own page, some text comes from a database using [data-bind](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html):

```
<div class="myClass" data-bind="text: MyText"></div>
```

The text appears, but no string operations are possible, I simply can't access it.

With:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass").innerHTML);
```

I get `undefined`.

I assume this is because the data-binding occurs **after** `console.log` is executed.

How can I access the string?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of DOMElements. If you're sure there's only one you can hard-code the array accessor:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML);
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fayu8e0h/)

Answer (score 0):

I think youre using a *div* tag but you should use a *input* tag:

```
 <input data-bind="value: MyText" />
```

If you only want to see the value of the observable 'MyText', you shouls look in your viewmodel.  Here you have an [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html).

Answer (score 0):

The string is in your viewmodel in the variable `MyText`. The whole point of Knockout is that you don't reach into the DOM to get at your data. It's in your viewmodel and the DOM merely reflects it.